# iOS Registration from website link

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller, appstore-approval

In `ViewController` i have button called registration for registor new user. And having textfield for enter userid, getstarted button take into `ViewController1`. If user click registration button UIWebview loads registration url from website link. After registration mail send to user with userid. Here what can i do after registration? shall i redirect to ViewController page for getstarted button. Shall i use navigation controller in UIWebview page for back. Sometimes apple will reject app that's why?

code:

```
webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,568)];
    NSString *url=@"http://myserver.net/projects/mobile/registration.php";
    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
    [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];
    [self.view addSubview:webview];
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't allow it.Even Google store also rejects such apps. Use API's or open signup page in safari as:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.signuPpaage.com"]];
```

But in this case user will have to relaunch your app manually again after signing up.

Comment: If after registration finish user need to close the app & relaunch again?